# Is there a CSS selector for any attribute with a specific value?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector that can target a specific attribute value regardless of its attribute? I am looking for something like `[*="value"]` (using a wildcard) or `{value}` (a direct value selector).

Comment: no, you will need js, to search for any attributes and then check the values found (if any) ..

Comment: @tylerH, why did you reopen the question? it seems a valid one for me

Comment: @TemaniAfif The dupe target that was chosen seems to be asking about any attribute with any value. This question is asking about any attribute with a *specific value*. Basically inverted what the other one is looking for, so not the same thing at all.

Comment: @TylerH I think the other question is asking for *any attribute with any value* which is IMO the generic case of *any attribute with a specific value*

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know it's 5 years late, but I've asked OP on that target question to clarify, because it seems unclear at the moment what exactly they're asking for there. If it seems like they're actually asking for "any attribute that contains x/specific value" then I'm happy to delete my answer here and re-close this.

Comment: @TylerH I doubt you will get a reply but let's wait

Comment: If you look at the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21222375/1) OP titled it specifically about any data attribute, with no consideration for what the value was. While I agree any attribute with any value is more generic than any attribute with a specific value, the question makes sense as a distinct one when inverted to "attribute selector *based on* a value"... it could certainly be possible for the latter to be achievable with a selector when the former is not (if the W3 spec decided to implement such a thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO**. We have to use any of the Basic Selectors or attribute selector.

Here is the list of all the CSS selectors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

You cannot find any of the value selector :)

Comment: ?? this is a comment, not an answser ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - this looks like an answer to me.  How does it fail to answer the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "have to use an attribute in Pure CSS"?

Comment: I meant any of the selectors dear friend :) Be it type, id , class, or advanced selectors, or wild card selectors etc .. Just provided an updated list of selectors as well :)

Answer (score 2):

No. CSS attribute selectors are designed to select based on the attribute (hence the name). If you want to select something based on a value rather than an *attribute* or *attribute value*, then just use CSS classes.

Alternatively, you can write a verbose selector that includes all the attributes your document will contain (because you should know that information ahead of time), e.g.:

```css
div[data-value="value"], div[href="value"], div[hello="value"], div[goodbye="value"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-value="value">Red</div>
<div>Black</div>
<div href="value">Red</div>
<div hello="value">Red</div>
<div goodbye="value">Red</div>
<div>Black</div>
<div>Black</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can select an attribute without an associated value by omitting the ="" in your selector. For example *[class] { display: none; } will hide any element with a class assigned to it.

Comment: But I want to target a specific value, a specific value regardless its attribute.